# Convert an array of hash with symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{'object' => 'ob1', 'quantity' => '2'}, {'object' => 'ob2', 'quantity' => '3'}, .....]
```

I want to convert it to symbolized form:

```
[{:object => 'ob1', :quantity => '2'}, {:object => 'ob2', :quantity => '3'}, .....]
```

tried with:

```
symbolized_array = array.each => { |c| c.to_options }
```

but i didn't obtained any conversion, the `symbolized_array` is same as array

why?

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, please consider [selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the one you found most helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Since ruby 2.5 there's `Hash#transform_keys`:

```rb
array.map{|hash| hash.transform_keys(&:to_sym) }
```

Before that it was available in activesupport (part of rails) along with shortcut `symbolize_keys`

Answer (score 7):

You tagged `rails` so you can use [`symbolize_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys)

```
array.map(&:symbolize_keys)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below code. Then you will get expected output

```
array.map! {|my_hash| my_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}}
```

**Or** simply you can use `array.map(&:symbolize_keys)`. This code will be work on rails environment

Answer (score 3):

> i didn't obtained any conversion […] why?

`to_options` does return a new hash with the keys symbolized, but you didn't use that new hash – `each` merely traverses the array and at the end returns the array.

If you want to pick up the blocks results as the new array element, you have to use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
array.map { |c| c.to_options }    # or array.map(&:to_options)
```

Alternatively there's [`to_options!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_options-21) (with a `!`) which would work along with `each`:

```
array.each { |c| c.to_options! }  # or array.each(&:to_options!)
```

That's because `to_options!` modifies the hashes in-place.

---

Note that `to_options` is an alias for `symbolize_keys` which might be a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks. And if i want to convert in an array of 'openstructed' objects, how to do? 
i've tried with openstructed_array=array.map { |c| OpenStruct.new(c) }, and there is a conversion, but if i try openstructed_array.first.object it give me error

Comment: @IdoTraini you should post a new question including example data and the error you're getting.